# Problems with CSS and javascript animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a website and have come across a stumbling point. I'm trying to include some animated image/caption on hover, but I can't, for the life of me, get it to work.. I'm getting very annoyed at this problem as it should not be a problem, I must be failing to see where I'm going wrong.

My website is:
[theystolemybaby.uk.undo.it](http://theystolemybaby.uk.undo.it), and the the picture towards the bottom of the page is supposed to animate like in the demo.. but it doesnt!

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!-- Author: Jamie Lindsey -->
<head>
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="1z0df9M7OshAE_NKuk-F46UbwLY9e4MabbypjmTCu_w" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://theystolemybaby.uk.undo.it/" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Coming Soon | theystolemybaby.uk.undo.it" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Our aim is provide a place to share the damage UK Social Services are causing thousands of families each year, a place to connect with others, to motivate, to inform, a network of thousands of bereaved parents, children, supporters, carers, whistleblowers. We need you all to be a part of what is to…" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://theystolemybaby.uk.undo.it/images/blue-eyes-baby-bg1.jpg" />
<meta property="og:updated_time" content="1443911486" />
<meta content="2015-10-06T12:21:00+01:00" property="og:article:published">
<title>Social Services Are Stealing Babies UK</title>
<meta content="The UK is the only country in Europe, and one of a tiny minority of countries in the world, that actively participates in Forced Adoption." name="description"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="keywords" content="theystolemybaby.uk.undo.it,Social services scandal,UK,Child Trafficking,Baby snatching,stealing,crime without punishment,forced adoption,Family,Social,Stealing Babies,Uk Social Services,Child,Services,Uk,Social,Care,Forced,Adoption,Children,Countdown Below Social,Court,Means,Local,Many,Social Services,Parents,Local,Authorities,Adoption,Again,Down Adoption Statistics,Birth,Uk,Only Country,Authorities" />

<!--css-->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="web/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="web/css/TimeCircles.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="web/css/header-effects.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="web/css/component1.css" />
<style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
 div.c1 {width: 100%;}
/*]]>*/
</style>

<!--/css-->
<!--javascript-->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="web/js/TimeCircles.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="web/js/waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="web/js/toucheffects.js"></script>
<!--/javascript-->
<!--fonts-->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<!--/fonts-->
</head>

<body>
<div class="container1">
<!-- start wrap -->
<!-- start content -->
</div>

<header id="ha-header" class="ha-header content-header">
    <div class="ha-header-perspective">
        <div class="ha-header-front">
            <h1> 
            <span>theystolemybaby.uk</span>
            </h1>
        <nav>
<!-- TODO create simple nav menu -->
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="ha-header-bottom">
            <nav>
                <a>Dalliance</a>
                <a>Inglenook</a>
                <a>Lagniappe</a>
                <a>Mellifluous</a>
                <a>Erstwhile</a>
                <a>Wafture</a>
                <a>Serendipity</a>
                <a>Love</a>
            </nav>
        </div>

    </div>
</header>

<br><br><br><br>

<div class="article-section-1">
<section>
<h2>Have UK Social Services stolen your child?</h2>
<p>This website is currently under construction but we are in the final stages of development.</p>
<p>(see the countdown below)</p>
<br>
</section>

<section class="article-section-1">
<h2>Social Services Are Stealing Babies in the UK!!</h2>
<p>Our aim is provide a place to share the damage UK Social Services are causing to thousands of families each year, a place to connect with others, to motivate, to inform, a network of thousands of bereaved parents, children, supporters, carers, whistleblowers.</p>
<p>The scandal is affecting too many of us to just sit back and do nothing.</p>
<p>Our voices - Your voices - need to be heard.</p>
<p>We need you all to be a part of what is to come!!</p>
</section>
</div>

<br>

<div class="article-section-2">
<section class="ha-waypoint" data-animate-down="content-header-solid" data-animate-up="content-header">
<h2>The ugly truth!</h2>
                <p>The UK is the <b>only</b> country in Europe, and one of a tiny minority of countries in the world, that actively participates in <b>Forced Adoption</b>. This Draconian act means taking a child away from his family without - and usually against - the agreement of all family members. Apparantly this is very much a last resort in a desperate situation, undergone when there is no safe way for children to stay with their immediate family. However, there’s no denying that this is done expeditiously and it is extremely brutal for those involved.</p>

<p>It is being claimed that the number of children with an Adoption Order has dramatically fallen. What this actually means is that there are still just as many children in the care system - for instance, being fostered - but fewer who have been recommended by local authorities to be placed for adoption by strangers. This basically means that because there is a massive profit to be made from fostering children - normally around £400 per week per child fostered - and the fact that so many people are aware of what is happening, Local Authorities are bending the rule books again and choosing to foster children off to starngers instead, this brings down adoption statistics and gets the attention away from the Local Authorities.This year alone, the number of children in care with an Adoption Plan fell again, by 37 per cent. For many of these parents, and children, cast adrift in a sea of uncertainty, this is a depressing state of affairs.</p>

<p>The key reason for this results from judgments made by the Supreme Court and the Court of Appeal which reminded local authorities and courts of the huge significance of adoption. Adoption legally and permanently severs the child’s legal relationship with their birth family. Again, the UK is the <b>only</b> country in Europe to do this, however often contact does continue with both siblings, grandparents and sometimes birth parents.  <b>Forced Adoption</b> is more accurately referred to in the care sector as ‘contested adoption’.</p>
</section>
</div>
<br>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://http://theystolemybaby.uk.undo.it" data-width="100" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
<section class="ha-waypoint" data-animate-down="ha-header-rotateBack" data-animate-up="content-header-solid">
<div class="timer-box">
<div class="timer-header">
<h2>We're counting the days 'til we're live..</h2>
<div id="DateCountdown" data-date="2016-01-12 01:00:00" style="width: 100%;">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
<section class="ha-waypoint" data-animate-down="ha-header-rotate" data-animate-up="ha-header-rotateBack">

<div class="clear"></div>


<ul class="grid cs-style-4">
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <div><img src="web/images/5.png" alt="img05"></div>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h3>Safari</h3>
                            <span>Jacob Cummings</span>
                            <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1116775-Safari">Take a look</a>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <!-- TODO
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <div><img src="web/images/6.png" alt="img06"></div>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h3>Game Center</h3>
                            <span>Jacob Cummings</span>
                            <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1118904-Game-Center">Take a look</a>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <div><img src="web/images/2.png" alt="img02"></div>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h3>Music</h3>
                            <span>Jacob Cummings</span>
                            <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1115960-Music">Take a look</a>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <div><img src="web/images/4.png" alt="img04"></div>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h3>Settings</h3>
                            <span>Jacob Cummings</span>
                            <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1116685-Settings">Take a look</a>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <div><img src="web/images/1.png" alt="img01"></div>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h3>Camera</h3>
                            <span>Jacob Cummings</span>
                            <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1115632-Camera">Take a look</a>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <figure>
                        <div><img src="web/images/3.png" alt="img03"></div>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h3>Phone</h3>
                            <span>Jacob Cummings</span>
                            <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1117308-Phone">Take a look</a>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
                 TODO END -->
            </ul>


<!-- start notify-->
<div class="notify">
<form>
<input type="text" class="textbox" value="Type your email here..." onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Email';}"/>
<input  class="md-trigger md-setperspective" data-modal="top-scorll" type="button" value="Subscribe"/>
</form>
</div>
</section>
<!--End notify-->
<!--start social icons-->
<div class="social-icons">
<h3>Social Sharing on the web</h3>
<ul>


<li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://theystolemybaby.uk.undo.it&amp;title=theystolemybaby.uk.undo.it%20|%20Coming%20Soon"><img src="web/images/facebook.png" title="Share on Facebook" alt="Facebook Share Icon" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="web/images/twitter.png" title="Share on Twitter" alt="Twitter Share Icon" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="web/images/g+.png" title="Share on Google+"  alt="Google+ Share Icon"  /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="web/images/rss.png" title="Rss"  alt="RSS Feed Icon"  /></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- End social icons-->
<!-- start copy right -->
<div class="copy-right">
<p>Design by <a href="#">Jamie Lindsey</a></p>
<br>
</div>
<!-- End copy right -->
<!-- End Content -->
<!--End wrap -->
</body>
<!--js-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#DateCountdown").TimeCircles({
        "animation": "smooth",
        "bg_width": 0.4,
        "fg_width": 0.04,
        "circle_bg_color": "#6cb7f9",
        "time": {
            "Days": {
                "text": "Days",
                "color": "#f9f68a",
                "show": true
            },
            "Hours": {
                "text": "Hours",
                "color": "#99CCFF",
                "show": true
            },
            "Minutes": {
                "text": "Minutes",
                "color": "#BBFFBB",
                "show": true
            },
            "Seconds": {
                "text": "Seconds",
                "color": "#FF9999",
                "show": true
            }
        }
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $head = $( '#ha-header' );
    $( '.ha-waypoint' ).each( function(i) {
        var $el = $( this ),
            animClassDown = $el.data( 'animateDown' ),
            animClassUp = $el.data( 'animateUp' );
    $el.waypoint( function( direction ) {
            if( direction === 'down' && animClassDown ) {
                $head.attr('class', 'ha-header ' + animClassDown);
            }
            else if( direction === 'up' && animClassUp ){
                $head.attr('class', 'ha-header ' + animClassUp);
            }
        }, { offset: '100%' } );
    } );
</script>
<script type="application/x-javascript">
<![CDATA[
addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); }
]]>
</script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<!--TODO <script src="web/js/toucheffects.js"></script> -->
<!--js-->
</html>`
```

And the CSS:

```
/* reset */
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,dl,dt,dd,ol,nav ul,nav li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-size:100%;vertical-align:baseline;}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {display: block;}
ol,ul{list-style:none;margin:0px;padding:0px;}
blockquote,q{quotes:none;}
blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after{content:'';content:none;}
table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
/* start editing from here */
a{text-decoration:none;}
.txt-rt{text-align:right;}/* text align right */
.txt-lt{text-align:left;}/* text align left */
.txt-center{text-align:center;}/* text align center */
.float-rt{float:right;}/* float right */
.float-lt{float:left;}/* float left */
.clear{clear:both;}/* clear float */
.pos-relative{position:relative;}/* Position Relative */
.pos-absolute{position:absolute;}/* Position Absolute */
.vertical-base{ vertical-align:baseline;}/* vertical align baseline */
.vertical-top{  vertical-align:top;}/* vertical align top */
nav.vertical ul li{ display:block;}/* vertical menu */
nav.horizontal ul li{   display: inline-block;}/* horizontal menu */
img{max-width:100%;}
/*end reset*/
body{

    background: url(../images/blue-eyes-baby-bg2.jpg) no-repeat #E7E7E7;
    background-color: #10CAD1;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 1400px ;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    /*background-position: top left bottom right;*/
    /* *** this will pan the background***
    -webkit-animation: mymove 180s infinite;
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    /* ***animation: mymove 180s infinite;*/
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    75% {background-position: center;}
}
/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes mymove {
    75% {background-position: center;}
}

body:after {
    background: rgba(134,6,71,0.7);
}
.container1{
    /*width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: transparent url(../images/pattern.png) repeat top left;
    z-index: 2;--*/
}
/*end reset*/
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
.wrap{
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
/* ---------- TIMER ---------- */

.timer-box {
    background-color: #92D9E1;

}
.timer-header h2{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 4em;
    font-weight: inherit;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

/*---start-content-header----*/

.content-header {
    background: rgba(228, 133, 186, 0.66);
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.content-header h1{
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 4em;
    font-weight: inherit;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    position:fixed; 
   top: 0px;
   margin:auto;
   z-index:100000;
   width:100%;
   text-align: left;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0%);
    transform: translateY(0%);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.content-header a {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: inherit;
    float: right;
    position:fixed; 
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.article-section-1 h2 {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 46px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.article-section-1 {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: inherit;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
}
.article-section-2 {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: inherit;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-left: 10%;
}
.article-section-2 h2 {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 46px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: rgba(146, 217, 225, 0.79);
}
//*---start-notify-form----*/
.notify{
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
    width: 50%;
    margin: 2em auto 0 auto;
    padding: 0.5em 2em 2em 2em;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}
.notify h3{
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #FFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 1em 0;
    word-spacing: 2px;
}
.notify input[type="text"]{
    width:80%;
    padding:12px;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}
.notify input[type="button"]{
    padding:12px;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    background: #10CAD1 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    color:#FFF;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.notify input[type="button"]:hover{
    padding:12px;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    color: #10CAD1;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.notify {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31);
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 2em;
    margin-top: 2em;
}
.notify input[type="submit"]:hover{
    background:#fff;
    color:#000;
}
.notify input[type="submit"]:active{
    background:#fff;
    color:#000;
    -webkit-animation: swing 1s ease;
    -moz-animation: swing 1s ease;
    -ms-animation: swing 1s ease;
    -o-animation: swing 1s ease;
    animation: swing 1s ease;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
/*---start-socail-icons----*/
.social-icons h3{
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 1em 1em 0.5em 1em;
    word-spacing: 4px;
}
.social-icons ul li{
    display:inline-block;
}
.social-iconsl ul li a{
    display:block;
}
.social-icons ul li img{
    display:block;
}
.social-icons ul li a{
    background: rgba(54, 239, 254, 0.25) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 30em;
    margin: 5px;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.2,0.77,0.75,0.48) 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.2,0.77,0.75,0.48) 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.2,0.77,0.75,0.48) 0s;
    -o-transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.2,0.77,0.75,0.48) 0s;
    transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.2,0.77,0.75,0.48) 0s;
}
.social-icons ul li a:hover{
    background: rgba(252, 246, 246, 0.56) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
.social-icons ul li a:active{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.8);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.8);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.8);
    -o-transform: scale(1.8);
    transform: scale(1.8);

}
.social-icons {
    text-align: center;
}
/*----start-copy-right-----*/
.copy-right{
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:1em;
    background: rgba(126, 146, 149, 0.53);
}
.copy-right p{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: inherit;
    word-spacing: 0.2em;
}
.copy-right p a{
    color: #10CAD1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.copy-right p a:hover{
    color:#fff;
}
/*-----start-responsive-design------*/
@media (max-width: 1440px){
    #counter {
        width: 67%;
        margin-left: 25%;
    }
    .digit {
        top: 9px!important;
    }
    .notify {
        width: 39%;
    }
    .notify input[type="text"] {
        width: 76%;
    }
}
@media(max-width:1024px){
    .content-header h1 {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 3.4em;
        margin:0 0 0.3em 0;
    }
    .notify {
        width: 50%;
    }
}
@media(max-width:768px){
    .content-header h1 {
        font-size: 2.5em;
        margin: 0 0 0.2em;
    }
    .content-header p {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 0.85em;
    }
    .notify {
        width: 57%;
    }
    .notify input[type="text"] {
        width: 71%;
    }
}
@media(max-width:640px){
    .content-header h1 {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
    .notify {
        width: 75%;
    }
}
@media(max-width:480px){
    .content-header h1 {
        font-size: 1.5em;
        margin:0 0 0.5em;
    }
    .content-header p {
        font-size: 0.8em;
        line-height: 1.6em;
    }
    .notify {
        width: 71%;
        padding: 1em;
        margin-top: 1em;
    }
    .notify input[type="text"] {
        width: 52%;
    }
    .copy-right p {
        font-size: 0.7em;
    }

}
@media(max-width:320px){
    .content-header h1 {
        font-size: 1.2em;
        margin: 0 0 0.5em;
        line-height: 1.6em;
    }
    .content-header p {
        font-size: 0.7em;
        line-height: 1.6em;
    }
    .content-header {
        margin-top: 5em;
    }
    .notify {
        width: 77%;
    }
}
```

The Tutorial and source for the Caption Hover Effects is:

[**On codrops here**](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/18/caption-hover-effects/)

I think it may be better not to include all the code as there is quite a lot and all the resources can be found in the links.

**The Question..**

Why is the animation not working?
I have linked all my css and javascripts correctly as far as I can tell (although I havent slept for 48 hours so I might be missing something stupid). Please ask if you require any more info and I will be happy to edit my question to include anything relevant. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You website is unreachable..

Comment: Your website is taking lightyears to load. Perhaps you should include the relevant code in the question.

Comment: your website not load.

Comment: I have added the HTML and CSS